# get result in same page and form

Tags: php, mysql

hello i have simple problem with my functions there is 2 codes :

i need when i put the right input answer echo $row['answer']; and sucess in next code.

it means i need when $_POST['answer'] = $row['answer']; echo my password

can someone help me with if cond.

this code is working perfect :

```
<?php 


$username = $_POST['username']; 


include('config.php');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE username='$username'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['username'];
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";
echo "<p><b>Secret Question</b></p>";
echo $row['secret'];
$freeanswer = $row['answer'];
}  
?>
```

code problem in same page :

```
</br>
</br>
<form action="" method="POST">
<p><b>Answer is :</b><p>
<input type="text" name="answer">
</br>
</br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>

 <?php 
$anme = $_POST['answer'];
if ($anme==$freeanswer) {
echo "sucess"; 
} else {
echo "wrong";
}

?>
```

Comment: What happens if I enter `' OR username!='` as my username? Always escape user generated strings before adding them to a query. More nefarious things can happen like having your database deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a name to submit button, and the check the existence of $_POST['name_of_button'];

This is a dirty example I wrote quickly so you can get the idea, I didn't test it

```
<?php
    // if the button has not been sent show the form
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>
    <form action="/test.php" method="POST">
        <p><b>Answer is :</b><p>
        <input type="text" name="answer">
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
 <?php
// otherwise means the form has been sent, show the password or wrong
    } else {
        include('config.php');
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE username='$username'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if($row) {
            if($row['answer'] == $_POST['answer']) {
                echo 'your password is ' . $row['password'];
            } else {
                echo 'wrong!';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can improve it please?

Comment: I tried to clean the code a bit and added some comments, but I don't have php installed in this laptop, I can't test it. Do you have any problems with the code ?

Comment: [10-Aug-2013 18:01:24] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/jordan/public_html/xpsbox/forgetaction.php on line 2

Comment: <?php
// otherwise means the form has been sent, show the password or wrong
    } else {

Comment: just copy the code in a file called test.php, you should see the form, and you can test it as a isolated example.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have problem sending the data?
If you want to post the form data to the same page you could use this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="post">
```

And this code will catch whatever you posted. (Put it in the same page as the form)

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['answer'])) {;
     if($name==$freeanswer) {
         echo "success"; 
     } else {
         echo "wrong";
     }
 } else {
     // Just for testing
     var_dump("No data sent yet");
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the **$freeanswer** variable declared in the second code?

This ***if*** statement is failing cause there is no **$freeanswer** declared.

```
$anme = $_POST['answer'];
if ($anme==$freeanswer) { ..
```

I see you declared it in first code but I dont see it in the second code..

EDIT :

Actually I didn't see It's all the same code. But still the problem is **$freeanswer** cause It's not declared in public scope It's only in the scope of **while** loop

Try declaring / writing this line of code here :

```
$username = $_POST['username']; // Near this line
$freeanswer = ""; // Declare this here
```